# Salesforce: CallReport trigger is not firing - Tests failing

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code

I am trying to deploy a small change to the trigger and I am getting warnings about insufficient (0%) Unit test coverage for another trigger (setTitle as shown below)

There is a test in place for this (please see below) but for some reason it is not getting taken into account. This test is defined similar to other tests which run successfully but in this case the trigger is not getting invoked (leading to the warnings for insufficient coverage)

Any ideas or suggestions where I can look and if there is any way to get past the test?

**Trigger Test:**

```
Call_Report__c c = new Call_Report__c(name='test cr', opportunity__c=o.id);
insert c;
```

**Trigger declaration:**

```
trigger setTitle on Call_Report__c (before insert)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I think **the best way would be to try running the unit test manually in your target org and examine the debug log**. And also manually check from UI if functionality still behaves as expected.

Some tips:

1. *(applicable only when deploying to sandboxes)* As stupid as it sounds are you sure the trigger is active? There's a checkbox when you edit them from UI or a status field in the accompanying metadata xml
2. Similar checkbox - is the trigger valid? If it was calling a method from class that was modified in the meantime you'll have a problem.
3. Do you have any recently introduced validations on the `Call_Report__c` or any prerequisites used in the test (like Opportunity):

   - fields marked as required in field definition,
   - shortened text field size but you're passing a too long string
   - Validation Rules (not on the `Call_Report__c` because [these are checked later](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm)), but on Opportunity etc.
4. Can you add some `system.debug()` to the test to make sure that Opportunity you're using is created ok. Also - sometimes developers are too much VF-centered and don't throw exceptions but swallow them and put VF error messages so check `ApexPages.hasMessages()` too.
5. *(more and more stupid stuff at that point)* ;) Class and function are marked as isTest / testmethod? Is that the only trigger on the object? If there are more `before insert` - you can't guarantee the order, maybe something fails over there?
6. ...

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for your detailed response, you got some great ideas here, I will go through these and see if any of these will help resolve the issue. Appreciate your comments!